# how to navigate the opened files in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I opened a files in vim using

> gf

command.which opened a file that the current cursor position.

I used

> ctrl + ^

is used to toggle between the last two opened files.
But,
How can i go forward and backward opened the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:bn` & `:bp` to cycle buffers

To cycle windows I use `ctrl+w+w`

To cycle opened file `:next` & `:prev`

To list opened buffers: `:ls`

from good old vi `:e#` reopens previous file ^^ (not using it since ages... well since VIM comes to my systems ^^)

EDIT: a quick test on gvim in windows (set nocp)

```
map <C-tab> ^[:bn^M
```

in order to enter escape (^[) and enter (^M) you have to press ctrl+v and then the special char

EDIT 2: a cleaner way to do this is putting this in .vimrc

```
map <C-tab> <esc>:bn<cr>
```

but just remember that using mnemonics for the keys depends on some other options (I cannot remember which one).

The best way is IMHO to write a VIM function saving the actual mode, performing switch and then restoring it, then mapping it to  in every mode (:[xxx]map commands)

Comment: It is woking fine...But,I need ESC mode.

Comment: you can add some custom mapping to force esc mode, cycle throu buffer and reenter edit mode. Somewhere there was a VIM script mapping this to ctrl+F6, will try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`:next` to next file
`:prev` to previous file

Comment: @sat: it helps to give more details.  'it is not working' is too broad to make any guess.

Comment: ,It is also working fine for opened files.I thought that this is for cycle buffers.That why,I put that comment.Don't mistake me.

Comment: it depends on how you files are opened. Launch a vim, do :e file1, then do :e file2, and try :next or :prev. You'll be suprised it will tell "there is only one file to edit", while if you do a :ls it shows 2 buffers.

Comment: @Jayan, :prev and :next only work when you open a files like that,  `vim a.txt hidden.php php_info.php` ..

Comment: @Jayan and @sat: This feature is called the argument list, and you can add files after launching (`:args *.cs`, `:argadd *.config`, `:rewind`). Be sure to look at `argdo` as well

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you might want to check out any one of the plugins trying to make buffer navigation easier

I myself have reduced it to `<leader>bx`, `x` being the number of the buffer.
Selecting the buffer is done via a nice popup list at the bottom.

To get this behavior, you would first install LustyJuggler ( https://github.com/vim-scripts/LustyJuggler ), and then set up the shortcut like so in your vimrc file:

```
nmap <leader>b :LustyJuggler<CR>
```

Note that this mapping only works when you are in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can also map the TAB key to quickly cycle through open buffers.

Add the following to your vimrc file:

```
:nnoremap <Tab> :bnext<CR>
:nnoremap <S-Tab> :bprevious<CR>
```